# How can I change the priority of network interfaces?

Tags: network-interface

Sorry for the complicated scenario.

OS is: CentOS 7

**Currently what happens:**

1. Server  boots.
2. Not  accessible through it's static IP.
3. Can connect to it through a local area IP (br160 192.168.160.27) on another server.
4. Once connected, I login through webmin, go to network interfaces, select the interface with the static ip assigned to the server (eno2 10.242.182.111), and click "save & apply".
5. The server can now access internet and I can connect to it directly through the eno2 IP (which is still on a closed VPN network, but that's how it should be).

So every time it boots I need to go and sort of reactivate eno2. It seems like it gets activated at boot (I checked), but maybe the priority is wrong?

ifconfig -a & route -n available here:
https://pastebin.com/vBcuw4Vt

cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2 :
https://pastebin.com/XJ9rhak8

I went from someone managing my server to that person leaving and me taking over. I can handle basic linux but not advanced networking.

EDIT: I am also seeing the boot routing as follows:

1. Any Interface to 192.168.160.11
2. eth0 to 10.242.182.1

Should I switch the order?

Comment: Can you add the content of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2`? In particular, that should have a line `ONBOOT=` which might be set to `no` for you?

Comment: Was just looking at it, I edited the post and put it here https://pastebin.com/XJ9rhak8 looks like onboot is on.

Answer (score 1):

Renumber the interface numbers by MAC-address. It looks like something goes wrong when givining eno0, eno1 and eno2 an IP address. You can assign another name to a MAC-address by placing a config file i say `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-persistent-net-rules`. Make a line for each interface with the desired MAC-address en device name (`eno0`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:11:22:33:44:55", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eno*", NAME="eno0"
```

Comment: Thanks! Would something like this work? https://pastebin.com/Ltwg6BRV

Comment: @AdrianP. that would be overkill.  you only need `udev` rules for the actual physical interfaces, `eno0`, `eno1`, and `eno2`.  The `br*`, `virbr*`, `docker*` etc interfaces are all based on (and defined relative to) the actual NICs (and are generally assigned to the correct parent interface when created by docker or whatever).  Also remember that most or all of those bridge interfaces are created dynamically when a container is created and may not be given the same name the next time an instance of that container is started.   a udev rule to rename it will just confuse docker.